# how to apply wildcard with sed in an hex string?

Tags: bash, sed, hex

I need a bash command to change a string in a binary file.

In the binary file I search for the string:

`AF7743**` and need to change to `AF774300`

How can i apply the wildcard so that sed change all the strings that start with my pattern and have only the last 2 values different ?

Tnx all

Comment: Does the file contain the string `AF7743`, or the bytes `AF`, `77`, `43`?

Answer (score 2):

Through sed.

```
sed 's/AF7743../AF774300/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'AF7743** foo AF7743kk' | sed 's/AF7743../AF774300/g'
AF774300 foo AF774300
```

Comment: you would need to add `-b` switch as the OP is editing a binary file.

Comment: In GNU sed and some others `.` matches all characters *including newlines* see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions)